# python __module__ dunder is __main__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

It seems like when I run a python program, the `__module__` dunder of a function would return the fully qualified path to the module of that function. It works, but has 1 exception - when the function is within the same file as my main. In which case, the `__module__` dunder would return `__main__`

say my directory structure looks like

```
| -- lib
|    |  util
|    |-- fileutil.py
|    |-- processutil.py
```

Say there's a function `foo` in `fileutil.py`. If I'm anywhere other than `fileutil.py`, and I do

```
fileutil.foo.__module__
```

I'd get `lib.util.fileutil`.
But if I'm making this call from `fileutil.py` itself, the I'd get `__main__`.

I want to **always** get the fully qualified path, so `lib.util.fileutil`, no matter where my main function is. Is there a way to do that?

EDIT -
The reason I'm doing this is that I need to keep a record of my function calls in a separate data structure.
For example, I'd like to know

On this day, at this time, I would like to run `lib.utils.foo` with these parameters.

This record would be a lot less useful if instead of `lib.utils.foo`, it said `__main__.foo`.

And note that sometimes I'm performing lazy eval, so I don't always actually run the function. That's why I can't actually make the function call and inspect the callstack.

Comment: To be clear, the module really is different. If `fileutil` is running as `__main__`, and some other module imported by it in turn import `fileutil`, it gets reimported separately (`sys.modules` has two separate entries for the same file). Are you sure you want to get those two things confused?

Comment: Thanks. I added some comments in my question to explain why I'm doing this. I think for my purpose, I don't want to distinguish the 2